# res.json is not sending my error message to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have this error handler that retreives specific error messages based on what happens. But the thing is when I run my error handler function with .catch() it will work if i'm logging to the node console, but when i try send it to the client via res.json() it will only send the status code, not any part of my error handler.

```
function errorHandler(error){
  if (error.name === 'SequelizeValidationError') {
    const errors = error.errors.map(err => err.message);
    return errors;
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
}


router.post('/create', async(req, res) => {
     await Movie.create(req.body)
      .then(() => res.json("Movie Created"))
      .catch( err => res.status(401).json(errorHandler(err)) );
  });
```

This is my code for the error handler and the route i'm talking about. It works in the node console, but like I said it only sends the status 401 code to the client and nothing else. How can I get my error message send to the client as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because its not waiting for result from errorHandler. Make them wait for it.
Try this.

```
function errorHandler(error, cb){
  if (error.name === 'SequelizeValidationError') {
    const errors = error.errors.map(err => err.message);
     cb(errors);
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
}


router.post('/create', async(req, res) => {
     await Movie.create(req.body)
      .then(() => res.json("Movie Created"))
      .catch( err => {
              errorHandler(err, function(errors){
                   res.status(401).json(errors);
               });
      });
  })
```

Or you can return a Promise and await on errorHandler.

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't work :( ... I appreciate you trying to help me though!! Thank you!

Comment: add console.log(errors) before res.status(401).json(errors) and show me the output

Comment: ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: Validation error: Please provide a value for "Title",
Validation error: Please provide a value for "Review"
    at C:\Users\jaybo\Desktop\sql-with-orm-node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:74:15
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\jaybo\Desktop\sql-with-orm-node\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)

Comment: It's logging my error message properly to the console, but that first line where it says provide a value for title is what I want to send via JSON.

Comment: where are you logging this? you have to debug your errorhandler function because it should return an array